# AWS EC2 (AWS Linux) how I access a private instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, amazon-ami

**I cannot access a private instance (AWS Linux)**
[What i try to do( Image )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVVeV.jpg)

I tried to access the **DB Server** instance(without public ip) using *ssh -i key.pem user@private_ip*, but it didn't work for me; As the **VPC** by default allows the connection between its subnets, try to upload the key.pem to the **WEB Server** instance and there I connect with *ssh -i key.pem user@private_ip*; but AWS does not allow me to upload to this file.

Could you help me with some guidelines on how to solve this problem please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but AWS does not allow me to upload to this file.

You upload it to your bastion using `scp`. If you can `ssh` to the bastion, you can `scp` your key as well.

But these days its probably better idea to use [ssm session manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html) to ssh to your private instance. This does not require any bastion host, and has many advantages over traditional `ssh` login.